# VB.NET get type of derived generic list class from list item method

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class notifierMain
    Public Class Contacts
        Inherits List(Of row)

        Public Sub New()
            Dim r As New row()

            Me.Add(r)

        End Sub


        Public Class row

            Public Sub Validate()

                Dim curType As String = Me.GetType().ToString

            End Sub

        End Class

    End Class

    Public Class MyContacts
        Inherits contacts

    End Class


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim c As MyContacts = New MyContacts()

        c(0).Validate()

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I debug this winforms application I get curType = "notifier.notifierMain+Contacts+row"

I want to the Validate function to know it is in MyContacts. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure to unserstand what you want to do exactly here. Can you provide an example of the expected result?

Comment: When a row is being validated (e.g. when its Validate() function is called), I want to know the type of the derived class that contains this row. So, in this case, the expected result would be "MyContacts".

Comment: What I really want is the container's derived type from within the row's validate function. Is there some general "container" or "parent" keyword that would get me this object?

Answer (score 0):

You're tostring()'ing gettype which returns a property called full name.
just check the .Name after get type and that'll have the result you want.

btw: this is a weird example, if you want validate() to return the name of the class you'll have to declare it as a function.

:)

Answer (score 0):

The `Me.GetType()` is always going to return the type of the class it is enclosed in.

You will need to change Validate to a function and pass in the type of object being validated, but then you might as well call `c(0).GetType()` outside if the validation anyway!

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for GetType

Answer (score 0):

You can explore your generic type as shown in this MSDN article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx

Hope this helps.